# How to run custom php script from doc root in magento2

Tags: magento2

I wanted to add custom php script to magento2 root folder and run from the browser.I tried to add it in magento2 root folder but it redirects to 404 page.

I also tried to add it in pub folder but no success.

Also cleared cache and empty generation folder.

I am using nginx server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using nginx configuration that comes with magento you need to put a file inside **`pub`** folder to allow access to it from the browser as pub is the document root of the vhost. Magento root dir is one level up. Second of all default config for nginx allows only to access `index.php, get.php, static.php, report.php, 404.php` and `503.php` files. Any other are not processed by the php. You can see this in line with `location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {` in **`nginx.conf.sample`**. If you are not using it check your config for similar rule. To allow another file to be accessible from browser simple add another name after 503 or change entire brackets with `location ~* \.php$ {`

**Source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97290/1883**

Comment: Thank you! Totally forgot that root folder is pub

Answer (score 0):

For example you can get product name in custom script by this step

**step 1: create index.php at root of magento 2**

> magento2/test/index.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '../../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('customScript');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

**step 2: create customScript.php**

> magento2/test/customScript.php

```
<?php
class customScript
    extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http
    implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface {
    public function launch()
    {
        $this->_state->setAreaCode('frontend'); //Set area code 'frontend' or 'adminhtml
        $id = 12;
        $_product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);

        echo $_product->getName();

        return $this->_response;
    }

    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Now you can run this custom script by

http://10.16.16.196/magento2/test/

[image]

Comment: ReflectionException: Class customScript does not exist ,getting this error

Comment: Are you creating `root/test/customScript.php` in same folder?

Comment: Yes index.php file and customScript.php created in same folder magento_folder/test/

Comment: @PrincePatel, we have set pub as root directory and the website in production mode, now getting pub/app/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: error

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Ranjit, the `/pub` folder **must be** your Magento root folder.
The correct way to run a standalone php script on Magento would be:

**On nginx:**

Locate `location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {` and add your file there.

I.e:
`location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check|myphp)\.php$ {`

Then you can access *yourstore.com/myphp.php*.

**On Apache:**

Simply add the file under `/pub` folder. I.e.: `/pub/myphp.php`.

Apache rewrites rule will redirect to `index.php` if the file or folder doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

In my case on Apache (cPanel) the problem was that file permissions of .php files should not be writable by group or others to be served directly, else Magento's 404 would open.

So in my case to serve file directly I had to set file permission to `-rw-r--r--` (on Linux).

This is the mostly issue with servers using suPHP.

Putting this here in case someone runs into same situation...